# Trait can be sometimes moved

Tags: rust, traits, move-semantics

I have a trait that looks like

```
trait Trait<T>
    where T: Data
{
    fn m1(&self) -> bool;
    fn m2(self) -> Box<dyn Trait<T>>;
}
```

Why is `m2` method with `self` even allowed? It's not like any of the trait impls can call that method because:

`cannot move a value of type dyn Trait<T>: the size of dyn Trait<T> cannot be statically determined`

That error makes sense but why can I can `push` trait objects in a container like `Vec` like so:

```
let trait_object: Box<dyn Trait<T>> = e;
let mut new_vec = Vec::new();
new_vec.push(trait_object)
```

So If trait object cannot be moved why does `new_vec.push(trait_object)` work?

Comment: You can call `m2` in a generic context. You just cannot use it with a dyn trait object: `fn foo<T1: Data, T2: Trait<T1>>(t: T2) { t.m2(); }`

Comment: Isnt this static binding?? Since `T2` will always be one type of Trait, there is no dynamic dispatch and hence `t.m2()` works?

Comment: Yes, you are right. As long as your type is `Sized` you will be able to call `m2`, dyn objects are not `Sized` but generic types are `Sized` unless you de-constrain them with  `: ?Sized`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dyn Trait<T>` is a trait object, which is different from having a constrained type variable that implements the trait.

A trait object uses dynamic dispatch and does not have a size know at compile-time - which is why you nearly always see trait objects behind a `&` reference or boxed. This is why the error message says `the size of dyn Trait<T> cannot be statically determined`.

Your trait can be implemented for any concrete (`Sized`) type. For example, for `i32`:

```
impl Trait<String> for i32
where
    T: Data,
{
    fn m1(&self) -> bool {
        true
    }

    // Can take self here because i32 is Sized
    fn m2(self) -> Box<dyn Trait2<T>> {
         make_boxed_trait_t(String::new())
    }
}
```

> why can I can `push` trait objects in a container like `Vec` like so:

This works because the trait objects in your example are boxed. `dyn Trait<T>` is unsized, but `Box<dyn Trait<T>>` has a size known at compile time. The size is the size of two pointers, because the layout of the a boxed trait object is always a pointer to the data and a pointer to the vtable of the type's implementation of `Trait`.

Comment: Makes sense. So when adding to container, it moves `Box` while with method call it tries to move stuff within the `Box`?